# In the controller.php file the query is incorrect which doesn't provide the correct path

Tags: php, jquery, web, path, widget

We are having an issue with our custom widget SolveCaseCreateNew and it looks like the issue is within the controller php file. The user will select a support contact for either Parts Help Desk or from Parts Distribution Center to create an incident on our Customer Portal. If the user selects Parts Distribution Center to create an incident and it has been resolved/closed, the user has the option to create a new incident by clicking the button "Need Further Assistance" on the CP that will reference the closes incident number. A new incident is opened but not under the original path of Parts Distribution Center. Regardless if it is a Parts Help Desk or Parts Distribution Center, it will automatically direct the user to open a new incident under the Parts Help Desk no matter how the original incident was created.

Below is the temporarily code to find what the value of `‘Team’` which is showing up as blank. The query must be incorrect and perhaps the else statement is wrong as well.

**Code (view.php)**

```
 <div id="rn_<?= $this->instanceID ?>_Label">
            <p><b>Case # <?= $this->data['ReferenceNumber']?> has been closed.</b> If you need further assistance on this case, click the button below.</p>
            <p><b>Team: <?= $this->data['Team']?></b></p>
            <!--<p>If you need further assistance, please click the button below to open a reference case for Case # <?= $this->data['ReferenceNumber']?>.</p>-->
        </div>
```

I believe the Query is the problem (snippet of code below), it is not pulling the correct path.

**Code (controller.php):**

```
  $incidentQuery = "SELECT I.ReferenceNumber, I.StatusWithType.StatusType.LookupName, I.CustomFields.c.support_team FROM Incident AS I WHERE I.ID = " . $i_id;
```

CONTROLLER.PHP

[controller.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VuaE.png)

VIEW.PHP

[view.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWVJC.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to see the table structure for Incident table to be able to help you with the query. Assuming the database is MySQL, you also could try to run your SQL query manually in PhpMyAdmin to get some ideas for troubleshooting.

For me, some of the field names seem to be very complicated. Maybe there is some misunderstanding there? Also, feeding the $i_id must produce the right syntax for the database. It seems to me that $i_id has to be a clean integer for your code to work.